# with ELB attached to ec2, health check failed on HTTP ping, but succeeded with TCP ping

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, amazon-elb

I was building backend for a simple app. It was with nginx-uwsgi-djangorest-api in AWS EC2.
Because I needed to send the requests with https, I added elb load balancer to my ec2 instance, which is forwarding HTTPS to HTTP.
ELB had to health-check the model. At first, I had "80:HTTP /health" ping for the health check and I was able to see the result in /health

but the health checker was always failing with `"GET /health/ HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"` showing on nginx and uwsgi log.

security group for ec2 instance

type - protocol - port range - source

HTTP - TCP - 80 - 0.0.0.0/0

HTTP - TCP - 80 - ::/0

SSH - TCP - 22 - 0.0.0.0/0

security group for load balancer

HTTP - TCP - 80 - 0.0.0.0/0

HTTPS - TCP - 443 - 0.0.0.0/0

configuration file for nginx

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/mysocket.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.compute.amazonaws.com *.elb.amazonaws.com;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I couldn't get what was wrong for hours and when I changed health check ping port and protocol to **HTTP:80/health** to **80:TCP**, it suddenly started working...

Can someone explain to me what does that health checker do?
I can't understand the difference between 80:TCP healthchecker and http healthchecker. this one doesn't have the /health/ url that was supposed to reach.

I also had the SSL certifications already.

- by http ping, even when I added this to nginx server conf file, the healthcheck was returned by 400 response.

```
location /health {
    return      200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP health check would just be checking that a TCP connection can be made, while an HTTP health check would be checking for a specific HTTP status code in the response. Is your health check URL not returning a `200` response?

Comment: If it is returning a `400` response, that's an error code, which will cause the health check to fail...

Comment: Yes I knew that... but couldn't fix it besides changing the ping protocol and port to 80:TCP